# Post modelcontaining HttpPostedFileBase file along with some parameters using form.serialize() in mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ViewModel containing some string and  HttpPostedFileBase  properties .
When i am posting the model to the controller using below ajax call,

```
 $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("_AddFeedback", "Mcq")',
                type: 'post',
                 data: $('form#frm-feedback').serialize(),
              //  data: formData,

                success: function (data) {
                    alert("done");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error occured while saving Option's data.");
                }
            });
```

I am getting  value for string but null for **HttpPostedFileBase**  type properties. How can we post HttpPostedFileBase   file using ajax ??

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot send files with AJAX, when serializing the form, but luckily there is another way, if you don't mind using HTML5. A short example, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery/8758614#8758614) answer:

**Markup:**

```
<form id="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($('#upload-form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("_AddFeedback", "Mcq")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

As stated, this is an HTML5 approach, which means it won't necessarily work in every browser. If this is a problem, see the thread I've linked to for other approaches to this problem.

Comment: Naveen said :ViewModel containing some string and HttpPostedFileBase properties. so it's not just HttpPostedFileBase property.also @Naveen  wants to serialize the form not append them to FormData.