# upload an image with mvc5

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

i am having trouble uploading an image from the website to the server.

My ajax form is taking everything except the image file.  I saw a similar question here [ASP.Net MVC 5 image upload to folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623947/asp-net-mvc-5-image-upload-to-folder)

but i can't seem to get it to work

i have this

```
public HttpPostFileBase imageFile {get;set;}
public string imageText {get;set;}
public string imageTitle {get;set;}
public bool isActive {get;set;}
public DateTime dateAdded {get;set;}
public string urlRedirect {get;set;}

public ActionView Index()
{
   return View;
}

public void UploadImage (CarouselController carouselImage)
{
 // some code
}
```

my ajax begin form takes in all the fields with html razor.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.imageText , new {class = "form-control"} )
... similar for the other fields. 
for the image i have 

@html.TextBoxFor(model => model.imageFile), new { type="file"})
```

this makes it a working selection input box but it doesn't pass any information to the upload method.

see attached picture for what i mean. 
[image]

Comment: Is imageFile the actual file or the location of the image?

Comment: i'm not sure. It's the the equivelant to <input type="file"/> so would that be the image or the location?  but either way i think it doesn't get passed because i have tried making HttpPostFileBase into string, Object, HttpPostFile, HttpPostFileBase, and in despiration i also tried a byte[]

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the following attribute on your form:

```
enctype = "multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: i'll give this a go. I wont be able to test it until a little later on.

Comment: No unfortunately this still ddin't work, it continues populating with a null.

Comment: And I also assume that your screen shot is out of date and your HttpPostFileBase is called "file" even though the screenshot calls it "imageFile"?

Comment: screenshot is the actual code. The other one is from memory. But i just checked, aside from the names. the code is pretty much spot on

Comment: In that case I would double check you have the right names on these attributes. If you are trying to post something named "file", the server will only bind it to something named "file"

Comment: What is it you passed as HttpPostFileBase type, inherited class or means that HttpPostedFileBase? Please check your code

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to send a file along with a form that is posted with AJAX. If that is the case, then that's your problem: You can't send files this way. AJAX form posting only supports plain text values. For a work around, see my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037303/post-modelcontaining-httppostedfilebase-file-along-with-some-parameters-using-fo/25042074#25042074) question.

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ImageUpload
{
        public int ID { get; set; }       

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }       

        [AllowHtml]       
        public string Contents { get; set; }

        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
     return View();
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Content", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype ="multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
   <input type="file" name="ImageData" id="ImageData" onchange="fileCheck(this);" />
}

[Route("Create")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ImageUpload model)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["ImageData"];

    ContentRepository service = new ContentRepository();

    int i = service.UploadImageInDataBase(file, model);

    if (i == 1)
    {
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}

private readonly ImageDBContext db = new ImageDBContext();

public int UploadImageInDataBase(HttpPostedFileBase file, ImageUplad imageupload)
{
        ImageUpload.Image = ConvertToBytes(file);
        var Content = new Content
        {
            Title = imageupload.Title,
            Description = imageupload.Description,
            Contents = imageupload.Contents,
            Image = imageupload.Image
        };

        db.Contents.Add(Content);

        int i = db.SaveChanges();

        if (i == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
}

public byte[] ConvertToBytes(HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    byte[] imageBytes = null;

    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(image.InputStream);

    imageBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)image.ContentLength);

    return imageBytes;
}

Step 6: Display an image form database on view. Here we display the content and image from the database.

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var content = db.Contents.Select(s => new
    {
        s.ID,
        s.Title,
        s.Image,
        s.Contents,    
        s.Description    
      });

      List<ImageUpload> imageModel = content.Select(item => new ImageUpload()    
      {    
            ID = item.ID,    
            Title = item.Title,    
            Image = item.Image,    
            Description = item.Description,    
            Contents = item.Contents    
        }).ToList();

       return View(imageModel);    
 }

<td>
     <img src="/Content/RetrieveImage/@item.ID" alt="" height=100 width=200 />
</td>

public ActionResult RetrieveImage(int id)
{
    byte[] cover = GetImageFromDataBase(id);

    if (cover != null)
    {
        return File(cover, "image/jpg");
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public byte[] GetImageFromDataBase(int Id)
{
    var q = from temp in db.Contents where temp.ID == Id select temp.Image;

    byte[] cover = q.First();

    return cover;
}
```

// Here is an example of how to upload an image and return its view. For more information, please refer to https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b696c4/how-to-upload-and-display-image-in-mvc/